# Mavericks + Server.app + getmail (oh my!)

Tags: email, server.app, imap

I have a Mac mini Server with OS X Mavericks 10.9.1 and Server.app v3.0 installed. IMAP (dovecot) is running and accessible from Mail clients.

What I want is to have the server fetch emails from my various email accounts and "dump" them into the IMAP server.

I was previously able to do this on Linux by using [getmail](http://pyropus.ca/software/getmail/) to fetch the emails, which would send the emails through `procmail`, which would deliver them directly into the Maildir folder which `dovecot` read.

Unfortunately the above process won't work with Server.app v3.0, as apparently the [`/Library/Server/Mail/Data/mail/*` directories *must* be owned by `_dovecot`](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5535262?tstart=0), which means Joe Random User can't write to them, which rules out procmail/etc.

Is there an easy(-ish) way to get a similar workflow, having the Server retrieve emails and add them to the local IMAP server?

What about server-side filtering? How can that be setup?

Comment: Have you tried using ACLs to get around the restriction that directories must be owned by `_dovecot`? (see http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/introduction-to-os-x-access-control-lists-acls/1048/.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an easy(-ish) way to get a similar workflow, having the Server retrieve emails and add them to the local IMAP server?

The key is to use the [`dovecot-lda` program](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/LDA) (*lda* for Local Deliver Agent), which can write messages into the IMAP server.

For example, if using `getmail`, you could provide a `[destination]` section which invokes `dovecot-lda`:

```
[destination]
type      = MDA_external
path      = /Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda 
arguments = ("-d", "USERNAME")
allow_root_commands = True
```

Note that `allow_root_commands` is required because `getmail` will need to be run as root to invoke `dovecot-lda`.

Aside: The path for `dovecot-lda` is specified in the postfix configuration file `/Library/Server/Mail/Config/postfix/master.cf`:

```
dovecot   unix  -       n       n       -       25      pipe
  flags=DRhu user=_dovecot:mail argv=/Applications/Server.app/Contents/ServerRoot/usr/libexec/dovecot/dovecot-lda -d ${user}
```

> What about server-side filtering? How can that be setup?

Dovecot is configured to use Sieve (`/Library/Server/Mail/Config/dovecot/conf.d/90-sieve.conf`). Sieve rules are stored in `/Library/Server/Mail/Data/rules/%u/dovecot.sieve` (see `/Library/Server/Mail/Config/dovecot/conf.d/90-sieve.conf`), which unfortunately isn't easily writeable.

To install additional Sieve rules, use a Sieve editor, e.g. [Sieve clients](http://sieve.info/clients). Note that you need to use the correct port (Server.app defaults to port 4190; see `/Library/Server/Mail/Config/dovecot/conf.d/20-managesieve.conf`).

Unfortunately, after spending far too much time trying to make this work, I've given up on using a Sieve client.

If you're root, create a `.sieve` file (verify syntax with `sievec`), then copy to `/Library/Server/Mail/Data/rules/%u/dovecot.sieve`. Note: `%u` is the user's GUID, not their user name (i.e. `/Library/Server/Mail/Data/mail/%u` should exist), and `/Library/Server/Mail/Data/rules/%u` should have permissions 775 (writable by the `mail` user).

If you're not root...get root and see above.

When the Sieve rules are in place, `/Library/Logs/Mail/mail-info.log` will contain a line similar to:

```
mail-info.log:Feb 13 17:14:52 lda(pid 6108 user USERNAME-NOT-GUID): Info: sieve: msgid=<whatever...>: ...
```